# MS Teams bot with SSO - Null reference exception while instantiating dialog state

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Microsoft Teams App with bot feature. SSO Authentication is done with Azure AD using package *Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs*. Conversation state is saved in Custom storage with Redis Cache. Followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-code?tabs=cs1%2Ccs2%2Ccs3%2Ccs4%2Ccs5&pivots=bot-app#consent-dialog-for-getting-access-token) for development.

Whenever a new user is trying to access the App, User gets the consent flow as expected after the consent is given App is throwing the below Null reference exception. App is working as expected without any issues/exception after few minutes. Assume this is due to some type of caching issue but not sure.

`at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.BuildDialogState(DialogInstance instance) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.CreateInnerDc(DialogContext outerDc, DialogInstance instance) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.<EmitEventAsync>d__41.MoveNext() at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<InternalRunAsync>d__1.MoveNext() at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext() at Teams.ControliQDialogBotHandler1.<OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in`

While debugging the issue found that bold section of Json object which is saved in Redis is the reason.

{"ConversationData":{"Workgroup":null,"WorkgroupId":1,"Client":"","ClientIdentifier":"","CiQToken":null},"DialogState":{"dialogStack":[{"id":"LoginDialog","state":{"dialogs":{"dialogStack":[{"id":"OAuthPrompt","state":{"options":null,"state":{"AttemptCount":0},"expires":"2023-03-06T12:50:49.9217743Z","caller":null},"StackIndex":null,"Version":null},{"id":"WaterfallDialog",
**"state":{"options":null,"values":{},"instanceId":"5c228607-a25e-4f1c-9a05-a258db893548","stepIndex":0}**,"
StackIndex":null,"Version":null}]}},"StackIndex":null,"Version":"PxgdwT2kgHXD18MXymvuyNERYjF3CBfAF9T/cbvv8rY="}]}}

Any help would be great ?

Comment: Could you please share the Bot Id and timestamp, so that we can investigate from our end?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Time stamp: 2023-10-27T10:54:16.5463674Z, id: 3c16056b-3bf5-4f73-8dac-db853fa47957